# How to protect your source code from theft?

Tags: security, embedded, code-access-security, source-code-protection

I came across an interesting interview question that what can be done in source code (written for embedded platforms) that it should **not** work properly after being stolen? I mean if one can benifit from IDE by running pre/post compiler scripts? Redefining macros etc etc? looking forward for your answers/ideas/tricks.

Comment: It seems that you have misunderstood the question - it is not about protecting the source code - the source code does not exist on the embedded system to be stolen.  If someone can replicate your hardware and steal the _object code_ by extracting from a device - that is perhaps the issue the interviewer intended.  Source code obfuscation is something you might do if you are distributing source code - but that is largely to prevent people making modifications and protection of _intellectual property_ and _trade secrets_ rather then preventing theft and reuse of the code.

Comment: Protect the source code or the compiled binary? In case of the latter, most MCUs come with copy cat protection nowadays. You can usually set it in a hardware mode that prevents read-out and then the only way to re-program the part is to erase everything. Which in turn is a good interview question, because anyone who's worked somewhat in-depth with microcontrollers during the past 20 years will know of this.

Comment: @Lundin protecting the source code. My answer was that in a bigger/large software, colleagues works with the module and to protect stealing provide them compiled libraries of stacks/drivers used (compiled and tested under certain conditions let say for Version1). So if they even steal the code that would not work completely for lets say Version2 which has a different configuration (compiler switches and so on).

Comment: @Clifford I asked again for the clearity if he mean the source code or the binaries flashed on the chip and the interviewer replied **source code**.

Comment: @BabarAli : So you ask him why he thinks there is a risk to the source code, and explain why you think there is no risk.  "_Don't ship the source code stupid is the answer_".

Comment: If you cannot trust your employees / colleagues not to steal the the company's intellectual property (not just code) code, you are in trouble as a business.  If you are not trusted by the employer, you don't want to work there.  Protection is by deterrent; making clear the the legal and/or career limiting consequences of intellectual property theft, and making clear your willingness to take necessary legal action against infringement.

Comment: @BabarAli It's protected by network security measures, not by programming. Or I suppose you could set up different access levels in your version control system.